# spring-boot-shiro customer filter not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, shiro

All

spring-boot run error:
There is no filter with name 'userAuthorizationFilter' to apply to chain [/**] in the pool of available Filters.  Ensure a filter with that name/path has first been registered with the addFilter method(s).

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.shiro</groupId>
        <artifactId>shiro-spring-boot-web-starter</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

shiroConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroConfig{

@Bean
public ShiroFilterChainDefinition shiroFilterChainDefinition() {
    DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition chainDefinition = new DefaultShiroFilterChainDefinition();

    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/css/**", DefaultFilter.anon.name());
    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/js/**", DefaultFilter.anon.name());
    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/images/**", DefaultFilter.anon.name());
    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/favicon.ico", DefaultFilter.anon.name());


    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/logout", DefaultFilter.logout.name());
    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/login", DefaultFilter.anon.name());

    chainDefinition.addPathDefinition("/**", "userAuthorizationFilter");
    return chainDefinition;
}

@Bean(name = "userAuthorizationFilter")
public UserAuthorizationFilter userAuthorizationFilter(){
    return new UserAuthorizationFilter();
}


@Bean
public UserRealm userRealm() {
    UserRealm userRealm = new UserRealm();
    return userRealm;
}

@Bean
public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager() {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager manager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    manager.setRealm(userRealm());
    return manager;
}
```

}

### [mvn spring-boot:run]Error Logs:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no filter with name 'userAuthorizationFilter' to apply to chain [/**] in the pool of available Filters.  Ensure a filter with that name/path has first been registered with the addFilter method(s).
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.mgt.DefaultFilterChainManager.addToChain(DefaultFilterChainManager.java:265)
at org.apache.shiro.web.filter.mgt.DefaultFilterChainManager.createChain(DefaultFilterChainManager.java:148)
at org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean.createFilterChainManager(ShiroFilterFactoryBean.java:397)
at org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean.createInstance(ShiroFilterFactoryBean.java:437)
at org.apache.shiro.spring.web.ShiroFilterFactoryBean.getObject(ShiroFilterFactoryBean.java:343)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168)
... 43 common frames omitted
```

Am I missing an essential part of the configuration?

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you did not assign an alias for your own filter "userAuthorizationFilter";

you should define the alias in the ShiroFilterFactoryBean initialization.

```
@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean getShiroFilterFactoryBean(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager, UserAuthorizationFilter  authorizationFilter) {

    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
    //...........................some other codes
    HashMap<String, Filter> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("userAuthorizationFilter",authorizationFilter);
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilters(map);

    //...........................some other codes
    return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
}
```